# No new data in gremling console of OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

How can I view fresh data from gremlin console of OrientDB?
I'm trying to do it like this:

```
 g = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/base");
g.V()
```

But it doesn't show all the vertexes. If I do g.V() from web interface of the OrientDB studio I see all existing vertexes.

Comment: Tried with OrientDB 2.0-SNAPSHOT and works. What version are you using?

Comment: It was orientdb-community-2.0-M3. Will try last one. Thanks